# How to run ansible tasks only when a specific tag is used?

Tags: ansible

I have a rather large playbook that contains tasks to install and configure a new application, with a bunch of tasks that are relevant only to the initial install and configuration, and a bunch of tasks that are only relevant for subsequent runs.

What I would like to do is conditionally include the tasks for the initial install and configuration, and run those only when an `initial-install` tag is passed.

For example:

```
# main.yml 
- include: initial_install.yml
  when: tag 'initial-install' specified

- include: initial_configuration.yml
  when: tag 'initial-install' specified

- include: configure.yml
```

This is a simplified example, but if I can figure this out, I should be able to organize my task list into a format that doesn't run the unnecessary tasks unless the playbook is being ran for an initial installation, with the `initial-install` tag.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is indeed a [full tagging mechanism](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_tags.html) build for you in Ansible already.

- You can either run only tasks with one or more tag(s):

  ```
  ansible-playbook play.yml --tags "some,tags,here"
  ```

  Where the tags specified is a comma separated list of all the tags you want to run.
- Or specify tag(s) you want to skip

  ```
  ansible-playbook play.yml --skip-tags "some,tags,here"
  ```

And you just specify your tags as a list on any task you need them:

```yaml
- include: initial_install.yml
  tags: initial-install

- include: initial_configuration.yml
  tags: initial-install

- include: configure.yml
  tags:
    - setup
    - reconfiguration
    - else
```

In your case, mind that

> Adding tags: to a play, or to statically imported tasks and roles, adds those tags to all of the contained tasks.

<sup>*Source: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_tags.html#tag-inheritance*</sup>

There is also a set of [special tags](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_tags.html#special-tags):

- `always`, is always run, unless specifically skipped via `--skip-tags always`
- `never`, is never run, unless another tag of that task is specifically requested

And a set of special keywords

- `tagged`, if you want to target all tagged tasks in `--tags` or `--skip-tags`
- `untagged`, if you want to target all untagged tasks in `--tags` or `--skip-tags`
- `all`, if you want to target all tasks in `--tags` or `--skip-tags`

---

Those can be used in your case:

```yaml
- include: initial_install.yml
  tags:
    - initial-install
    - never

- include: initial_configuration.yml
  tags: 
    - initial-install
    - never

- include: configure.yml
  tags:
    - setup
    - reconfiguration
    - else
```

- Running this example via plain

  ```
  ansible-playbook play.yml
  ```

  won't run the two first task, but will run the last one.
- Running it with

  ```
  ansible-playbook play.yml --tags "initial-install,all"
  ```

  will run all three tasks.

---

Given the playbook:

```yaml
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: no  
        
  tasks:
    - debug: 
        msg: initial_install.yml
      tags:
        - initial-install
        - never

    - debug: 
        msg: initial_configuration.yml
      tags: 
        - initial-install
        - never

    - debug: 
        msg: configure.yml
      tags:
        - setup
        - reconfiguration
        - else
```

This gives those outputs:

- ```
  $ ansible-playbook play.yml 

  PLAY [all] ******************************************************

  TASK [debug] ****************************************************
  ok: [localhost] =>
    msg: configure.yml

  PLAY RECAP ******************************************************
  localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0
  ```
- ```
  $ ansible-playbook play.yml --tags "initial-install,all"

  PLAY [all] ******************************************************

  TASK [debug] ****************************************************
  ok: [localhost] =>
    msg: initial_install.yml

  TASK [debug] ****************************************************
  ok: [localhost] =>
    msg: initial_configuration.yml

  TASK [debug] ****************************************************
  ok: [localhost] =>
    msg: configure.yml

  PLAY RECAP ******************************************************
  localhost                  : ok=3    changed=0    unreachable=0
  ```

Comment: In your example, wouldn't `configure.yml` run if there were no tags specified when `ansible-playbook` was ran? I need these task files to be included IFF a tag is specified when `ansible-playbook` is invoked.

Comment: Then you are looking for `never`. Let me enhance the answer